# Make package redirect to another package

Tags: java, package

I want to make a package redirect to another package. For example I have a package called "packageA" and another called "packageB", and importing packageA would import packageB. I want to be able to do this without copying the package. Also, is there any way to run a method if packageA was imported instead of packageB?

Comment: Java doesn't have this "feature".

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: What is the real problem which you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at how the `import` statement works:

First of all, `import` only imports classes or interfaces. It **never** imports a package. In particular, something like

```
import java.util.*
```

imports all the **classes and interfaces** in the package named `java.util`. This package is simply a container for the classes and interfaces, so it really doesn't make any sense to talk about "importing a package". A package by itself isn't anything that compiles or runs.

With that said, it doesn't make any sense to talk about "redirecting" because what are you going to redirect to? If you want to import a class from "packageA", just import it directly.

Similarly, importing a class from packageA gives you access to that's classes methods. Since that class lives in packageA, it doesn't make any sense trying to import it from packageB. Even if packageB has a class with the same name, they are two different classes. In fact, this is the primary reason for packages in Java: to avoid name clashes for classes written by two different programmers.

With all that said, what problem have you encountered that you are trying to solve with "redirecting imports"?

Comment: I want to make people who use my jar to be able to use the old package name AND the new package name. Can the class be in two packages at the same time?

Comment: @Runemoro No, two classes in two package are two different classes. One way to solve the problem is to create class `A` in packageA and another class named `A` in packageB which extends `packageA.A`.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Long answer:
A package is part of the class and `import`statements are read at compile time, they are not interpreted. What you want would have to be done by a twisted Java compiler. Since some compilers are open-source this *possibly* could be done but don't expect to find such a feature.

Alternative answer: If you are using an IDE like Netbeans, Eclipse, etc. There are plenty of refactoring tools that could help you changing a package name into another.